# Excepción a leer con FileInputStream

Tags: android, android-studio

Heredé un proyecto antiguo desarrollado en **Android 4** con Eclipse, el cual tengo que migrar a Android 7. Importé el proyecto en **Android Studio**. Para leer un archivo a través de `FileInputStream` estoy obteniendo una excepción. La ruta del archivo es en una carpeta en la **SdCard**. Lo estoy depurando en el `AVD`.

```
public User getUserAdmin(String username, String password)
        throws UserManagerException {
    try {
        User user = null;
        String passEncript = "";
        String comparepass="";

        passEncript = SimpleCrypto.sha1(password);
        try {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/FilesEnt/.masterpwd.key");

            FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fileIS));
            String readString = new String();
            // just reading each line and pass it on the debugger
            while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.v("readString", "string"+readString);
                comparepass+=readString;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        if (passEncript.equals(comparepass)) {
            user = new User();
            user.setUser_name(username);
            user.setName(ParamManager.ADMIN_USER);
            user.setRole(ParamManager.ROLE_ADMIN_USERS + "");
            String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(cont.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            user.setTablet_id(androidId);
        }
        return user;
    } catch (SimpleCryptoException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        throw new UserManagerException("Error al cifrar el password", e1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                "Error al tratar de sacar datos de la base de datos local!!!!!!");
        throw new UserManagerException(
                "Error al leer archivo de configuración de usuarios", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: /.masterpwd.key el punto delante masterpwd, en la ruta,¿ tiene sentido?

Comment: Hola Juan, es **muy importante agregar el mensaje de error** cuando preguntes ya que pueden existir varias razones para que tu aplicación no funcione adecuadamente y ayudará a resolver rápidamente la problemática, revisar [ask].

Comment: El error que me sale es Permiso denegado para acceder al archivo .masterpwd.key. El nombre de archivo .masterpwd.key no es relevante, de hecho lo renombre a masterpwd.key. ¿Habrá que dar algún permiso de root a mi virtual?